# How can I interpret a masking system in my login system?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, masking

I'm just not sure how I can mask with the addition of arrays. I would also like the masking system to recognize backspace not as a letter.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim memofs As Char
    Dim stdntpassword As String = Nothing
    Dim staffpassword As String = Nothing
    Console.Write("Are you a member of staff? (y/n) ")
    memofs = Console.ReadLine
    If memofs = "y" Or memofs = "Y" Then

    ElseIf memofs = "n" Or memofs = "N" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Password: ")
        stdntpassword = Console.ReadLine
    End If

    For attempts As Integer = 1 To 5

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Attempt Number " & attempts)
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write("Password: ")
        staffpassword = Console.ReadLine
        Dim fullline As String = ""
        FileOpen(1, _
          "E:\Computing\Spelling Bee\StaffPasswords\staffpassword.csv", OpenMode.Input)
        fullline = LineInput(1)
        Dim item() As String = Split(fullline, ",")
        If staffpassword = item(0) Then
            Console.Clear()
            staffmenu()
        Else : FileClose(1)
        End If
        Console.Clear()
```

Appreciated,

Answer (score 3):

I've done this once before, but instead of masking the password with, say an asterisk, I just left it blank (like entering a password in Linux). The latter is pretty straightforward:

```
Dim keyInfo as ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(True)
Dim enteredPassword as String = ""
' Read each entered character until user presses Enter.
While keyInfo.Key <> ConsoleKey.Enter
   If keyInfo.Key = ConsoleKey.Backspace AndAlso enteredPassword.Length > 0 Then
       enteredPassword = enteredPassword.Substring(0, enteredPassword.Length - 1)
   Else
       password &= keyInfo.KeyChar
   End If
   ' Read next entered character
   keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(True)
End While
```

To actually mask the password input, use the same idea, but after each character is entered and parsed, add a `Console.Write("*"c)`. This get's a bit tricky with backspace, and the only way I know to simulate it would be to do:

```
Console.Write(ControlChars.Back)' move cursor back one column
Console.Write(" "c) ' clear the asterisk
Console.Write(ControlChars.Back)' move cursor back again to allow writing.
```

It's a bit prettier in C# in my opinion (and works using `'\b'` instead of `ControlChars.Back`) so your results may vary.

Also if there's an easier way to do this, I'd *love* to know, as this seems like reinventing the wheel for a fairly simple task.