# Could someone help me with my login system by adding password masking system

Tags: vb.net, authentication, console-application

I can't find a way round in adding a code which doesn't treat the backspace button as a character. It would be great if someone could implement a few lines of code in order to make it possible for the program to delete letters, whilst not perceiving the backspace button as a letter.

```
Dim fullline As String = ""
FileOpen(1, "E:\Computing\Spelling Bee\StaffPasswords\staffpassword.csv", OpenMode.Input)
fullline = LineInput(1)
Dim item() As String = Split(fullline, ",")
Dim info As ConsoleKeyInfo
Console.Write("Password: ")
Dim enteredpassword As String = ""
Dim password As String = fullline

Do
    info = Console.ReadKey(True)
    If info.Key = ConsoleKey.Enter Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        enteredpassword &= info.KeyChar
        Console.Write("*"c)

    End If

    If enteredpassword = password And ConsoleKey.Enter Then
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Works")
    End If

Loop
Console.WriteLine()
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: split()-ing on a comma is a horrible way to parse csv data

Comment: Have you consulted the answer I posted the last time you asked this? If not let me know and I can take another look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248057/how-can-i-interpret-a-masking-system-in-my-login-system/20249973#20249973

Comment: Also: plain-text passwords are evil evil evil

Comment: I'm very new to coding, and I'm still within the basic stages.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim item() As String
Using rdr As New TextFieldParser("E:\Computing\Spelling Bee\StaffPasswords\staffpassword.csv")
    rdr.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
    rdr.Delimiters = New String() {","c}
    item = rdr.ReadFields()
End Using

Console.Write("Password: ")

Dim enteredpassword As String
Dim password As String = item(0)
Dim info As ConsoleKeyInfo

Do
    info = Console.ReadKey(True)
    If info.Key = ConsoleKey.Enter Then Exit Do

    If info.Key = ConsoleKey.BackSpace AndAlso enteredpassword.Length > 0 Then
        enteredpassword = enteredpassword.SubString(0, enteredpassword.Length -1)
        Console.Write(vbBack)
    Else
        enteredpassword &= info.KeyChar
        Console.Write("*"c)
    End If 
Loop

If enteredpassword = password Then
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Works")
End If 

Console.WriteLine()
Console.ReadKey(True)
```